# How to calculate the difference between rows in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This is my DataFrame in PySpark:

```
utc_timestamp               data    feed
2015-10-13 11:00:00+00:00   1       A
2015-10-13 12:00:00+00:00   5       A
2015-10-13 13:00:00+00:00   6       A
2015-10-13 14:00:00+00:00   10      B
2015-10-13 15:00:00+00:00   11      B
```

The values of `data` are cumulative.

I want to get this result (differences between consecutive rows, grouped by `feed`):

```
utc_timestamp               data    feed
2015-10-13 11:00:00+00:00   1       A
2015-10-13 12:00:00+00:00   4       A
2015-10-13 13:00:00+00:00   1       A  
2015-10-13 14:00:00+00:00   10      B
2015-10-13 15:00:00+00:00   1       B
```

In `pandas` I would do it this way:

```
df["data"] -= (df.groupby("feed")["data"].shift(fill_value=0))
```

How can I do the same thing in PySpark?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `lag` as a substitute for `shift`, and `coalesce( , F.lit(0))` as a substitute for `fill_value=0`

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

window = Window.partitionBy("feed").orderBy("utc_timestamp")

data = F.col("data") - F.coalesce(F.lag(F.col("data")).over(window), F.lit(0))
df.withColumn("data", data)
```

Comment: You can avoid the use of coalesce setting in lag function the value 0 on default:

lag(col, offset=1, default=0)

Answer (score 21):

You can do this using [lag](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lag) function with a window:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

window = Window.partitionBy("feed").orderBy("utc_timestamp")

df = df.withColumn("data", f.col("data") - f.lag(f.col("data"), 1, 0).over(window))
```