# How to use pyspark to do some calculations of a csv file?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am working on one CSV file below using PySpark(on databricks), but I am not sure how to get the total scan (event name) duration time. Assume one scan per time.

|  | timestamp | event | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-11-17_19:15:33.438102 | scan | start |
| 2 | 2020-11-17_19:18:33.433002 | scan | end |
| 3 | 2020-11-17_20:05:21.538125 | scan | start |
| 4 | 2020-11-17_20:13:08.528102 | scan | end |
| 5 | 2020-11-17_21:23:19.635104 | pending | start |
| 6 | 2020-11-17_21:33:26.572123 | pending | end |
| 7 | 2020-11-17_22:05:29.738105 | pending | start |
|  | ......... |  |  |

Below are some of my thoughts:

## first get scan start time

```
scan_start = df[(df['event'] == 'scan') & (df['value'] == 'start')]

scan_start_time = scan_start['timestamp']
```

## get scan end time

```
scan_end = df[(df['event'] == 'scan') & (df['value'] == 'end')]

scan_end_time = scan_start['timestamp']
```

## the duration of each scan

```
each_duration = scan_end_time.values - scan_start_time.values
```

## total duration

```
total_duration_ns = each_duration.sum()
```

But, I am not sure how to do the calculation in PySpark.

First, do we need to create a schema to pre-define the column name 'timestamp' type in timestamp? (Assume all the column types (timestamp, event, value) are in str type)

On the other hand, assume we have multiple(1000+files) similar to the above CSV files stored in databricks, how can we create a reusable code for all the CSV files. Eventually, create one table to store info of the total scan_duration.

Can someone please share with me some code in PySpark?
Thank you so much

Comment: Do events have an id to identify them? Are scans run sequentially, that means a new scan can only start after the previous one has ended? Does the dataframe come already sorted by timestamp? How do you want to deal with "pending" events?

Answer (score 0):

This code will compute for each row the difference between the current timestamp and the timestamp in the previous row.

I'm creating a dataframe for reproducibility.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Window
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace, col, lag
import pandas as pd

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("DataFarme").getOrCreate()
data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "timestamp": ["2020-11-17_19:15:33.438102","2020-11-17_19:18:33.433002","2020-11-17_20:05:21.538125","2020-11-17_20:13:08.528102"],
        "event": ["scan","scan","scan","scan"],
        "value": ["start","end","start","end"]
    }
)
df=spark.createDataFrame(data)
df.show()
# +--------------------+-----+-----+                                              
# |           timestamp|event|value|
# +--------------------+-----+-----+
# |2020-11-17_19:15:...| scan|start|
# |2020-11-17_19:18:...| scan|  end|
# |2020-11-17_20:05:...| scan|start|
# |2020-11-17_20:13:...| scan|  end|
# +--------------------+-----+-----+
```

Convert "timestamp" column to `TimestampType()` to be able to compute differences:

```
df=df.withColumn("timestamp",
regexp_replace(col("timestamp"),"_"," "))
df.show(truncate=False)
# +——————————-------------———+---——+—---—+
# |timestamp                 |event|value|
# +————————————-------------—+---——+—---—+
# |2020-11-17 19:15:33.438102|scan |start|
# |2020-11-17 19:18:33.433002|scan |end  |
# |2020-11-17 20:05:21.538125|scan |start|
# |2020-11-17 20:13:08.528102|scan |end  |
# +——————————-------------———+---——+---——+

df = df.withColumn("timestamp",
regexp_replace(col("timestamp"),"_"," ").cast(TimestampType()))
df.dtypes
#  [('timestamp', 'timestamp'), ('event', 'string'), ('value', 'string')]
```

Use [`pyspark.sql.functions.lag`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.lag.html#pyspark-sql-functions-lag) function that returns the value of the previous row (offset=1 by default).
See also [How to calculate the difference between rows in PySpark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65098912/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-rows-in-pyspark) or [Applying a Window function to calculate differences in pySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36725353/applying-a-window-function-to-calculate-differences-in-pyspark)

```
df.withColumn("lag_previous", col("timestamp").cast("long") - lag('timestamp').over(
    Window.orderBy('timestamp')).cast("long")).show(truncate=False)
# WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
```

Using Window without partition gives a warning.
It is better to partition the dataframe for the Window operation, I partitioned here by type of event:

```
df.withColumn("lag_previous", col("timestamp").cast("long") - lag('timestamp').over(
    Window.partitionBy("event").orderBy('timestamp')).cast("long")).show(truncate=False)
# +———————————-------------——+---——+—---—+—------—————+
# |timestamp                 |event|value|lag_previous|
# +———————————-------------——+---——+---——+------——————+
# |2020-11-17 19:15:33.438102|scan |start|null        |
# |2020-11-17 19:18:33.433002|scan |end  |180         |
# |2020-11-17 20:05:21.538125|scan |start|2808        |
# |2020-11-17 20:13:08.528102|scan |end  |467         |
# +—————-------------————————+---——+—---—+—------—————+
```

From this table you can filter out the rows with "end" value to get the total durations.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. However, what about if I have multiple files that need to be tested out. Are there any other special steps that I need to do?

Comment: @Lawrence you can load them all in a dataframe if they have the same format, just give the name of the input folder in place of the input file

Comment: thank you for all the suggestions!!